# This is a play on number

Tags: riddle

This riddle is driving me crazy I know it's as plain as the nose on my face but I still can't figure it out because I'm trying to be too logical or analytical more to the point.
[image]

Comment: It might be reverse psychology and like you said it might be c

Comment: It might be c because it has two (times) zero and (two) times four. It might be b because it has two (2) zero two four. It might be a because it has two (times) zero two (2) four.

Comment: Is the picture relevant to the solution? If not, it can be transcribed and the picture eliminated. Also, do you have a solution to the riddle, or is this one you are genuinely stumped on?

Comment: Where is $2044$?

Answer (score 7):

There are reasons why it could be any of the three given options:

> A: `0024` is "Two Zeroes, Two, Four"
>  B: `2024` is "Two, Zero, Two, Four"
>  C: `0044` is "Two Zeroes, Two Fours"

Without knowing more about the context or the person asking the question, there's no real way to determine which one it is.

Comment: Although you could argue that b) is preferable because it is the only sentence which is exactly equal to the description, i.e. Zero and Four, not Zeroes or Fours.

Comment: In addition, b) is the only answer in which both parts are interpreted the same.

Comment: The question is from a meme that trended last week.

Comment: I agree with this explanation, and that it means the answer is B as it has the correct pluralisation.

Answer (score 4):

As DqwertyC states, all could be correct (is "all of the above" a valid answer?).

> However, if I had to pick one, it would be B, as considering the phrasing of the question ("two zero and two four") and that it does not use plurals ("two zeros" or "two fours"), B is the closest match as both A and C should properly be "two zeros" and then a description of the second half - either "two four" for A or "two fours" for C.

This is almost like a language test.

> The answer could also be "none of the above" as the question is "which **one** has", and there are no ones, much less any that meet the requested criteria. Some riddles are like that.

Comment: +1 ... Regardless, tell them to go learn English again

Answer (score 0):

I like

> 'C' because it's correct twice

**Which one has two zero and two four?**

> Using digits for counters and words for symbols (and ignoring plurals):
>  
>   - A has either 2 zero and two four - internally inconsistent 
>                OR zero zero and two four - incorrect
>
>   - B has two zero and two four - correct
>
>   - C has 2 zero and 2 four - correct
>  
>  
>  Using addition (where 'and' represents 'plus'):
>  
>   - A has two zero plus zero four - incorrect 
>  
>   - B has two zero zero zero plus two four - incorrect
>  
>   - C has two zero plus two four - correct

Answer (score 0):

> I think it is C because it is a play on words. Which one has two 0 and two 4.
> If they wanted the numbers to be taken as a list like in B they could have simply added the and before the last number.
> Which one has two, zero, two, and four?
> A plays into both B and C
> Which one has 2 zero, two and four?

Answer (score 0):

It is:

> None of them. The correct answer is $2044$, two zero and two fours.